# Jboss 7.2.2 Sticky session issue with load balancer

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

We are facing sticky session issues while working on jboss cluster environments with load balancer. We have a application with File Upload functionality. In this feature, we are creating temporary file in temp folder(java.io.tmpdir) and then processing it.

The present behaviour of both jboss node (2 nodes) is configured due to this, suppose a scenario that during file upload process from user it is handled by node1, and now here the file will upload on java.io.tmpdir  of node1. Following to this there are some sequence of processes that are now executing to process uploaded file from node2 of jboss, and are failing as are trying to search file on java.io.tmpdir  of node2 (but actual file is on node1 of temp directory).

As suggested by in many forums, I tried to add distributable tag in web.xml and also added the below code in jboss-web.xml

```
<replication-config>
    <replication-granularity>SESSION</replication-granularity>
</replication-config>
```

But above code is not working for me. Can you suggest me some solutions to resolve above issue?

Comment: Just mount a shared storage at os level for both nodes and configure application to use it.

Comment: That is last solution we are thinking of.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that? Same code is working fine with weblogic.